# Freemarker template is not replaced with data model

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I have followed the steps given in this link [Demo](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-mail-sending-email-freemarker-html-template-example/) and I am able to print out the template but after calling the below code and when I print html, it returns back the template minus the data. For example, "Dear ${user}," is simply "Dear ,"

```
String html = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t, model);
```

Am I missing something.I don't see any TemplateException.

Comment: Could this be because it is being interpreted as jstl tags

Comment: That's quite strange given that if `user` is missing from the data-model or is `null`, FreeMarker will not just print nothing, but throw an exception. (Unless you are using a custom `TemplateExceptionHandler` that suppresses the problem.) Maybe you need to check the content of `model` more closely. Like log the user name in it before calling FreeMarker, just so we can see it's not `""`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I printed the model contents and they are fine. A little more info about my implementation. I am publishing my template as an ftl file but the components are embedded from jsp pages. Does that make sense? I am getting the template from URLTemplateLoader. So maybe before the ftl file is loaded the page tags are resolved. ${} is considered as jstl.

Comment: I don't follow how do you mix FTL and JSP... Like how do you embedded those components?

Comment: Well we use SDL as our CMS and like any, we can publish a page that contains many components. The inner components are usually jsp or jstl tags and then all the components are published inside this page to form the final .ftl file.

Comment: So then its to be expected that JSP will resolve the `${}`-s, before it gets to FreeMarker, right? To work that around, you will have to use a syntax that doesn't clash with JSP. The option for using `[=exp]` instead of `${exp}` is a planned feature for 2.3.28, so maybe that will help... until that, do a simple search-and-replace programmatically (`[=exp]` to `${exp}`) before FreeMarker gets the template.